# sorting by date for files and A-Z for folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sorting

what I want to do is to create something like windows sorting.
in windows, you can have different sorting for folder and subfolder.
in each document library, we have some top-level folders I want this to be sorted based on A-Z
then when you go inside there are either files or folders. if there are only files I want them to be sorted by date. If it again folders I want them to be sorted A-Z

is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, that is not possible to achieve in SharePoint Online.
SharePoint does not provide the ability to apply different sorting methods based on content types or folder structures, but just columns.

I would propose that you share this idea via the SharePoint UserVoice forum: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration